# Http 400 'Bad Request' and win32status 1450 when larger messages are sended to a WCF service

Tags: iis-6, http, wcf, 400

we sometimes receive Http 400 bad request resultcodes when posting a large file (10mb) to a WCF service hosted in IIS 6. We can reproduce this using SOAP UI and it seems that it is unpredictable when this happens. In our WCF log the call is not received, so we believe that the request does not reach the ASP.NET nor WCF runtime. This happens on multiple websites on the same machine each having their own application pool. All IIS settings are default, only in ASP.NET and WCF we allow bigger readerQuota's etc....

The win32status that is logged in the IIS log is 1450 which we think means "error no system resources".

So now the question:
a) how can we solve this
b) (when a is not applicable :) ) which performance counters or logs are usefull to learn more about this problem?

greetings,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

check this articles [KB810957](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810957) which explains the cause of the issue and [UploadReadAheadSize](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/48900606-4881-4a93-a4c1-0e0ac622fee6.mspx?mfr=true) is the solution for the same.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: yes we already read this, but I would think that if this setting is set too low that every request should fail...

Comment: if you upload the file thats larger than 4.8KB will fail. Have you also checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325275/in-wcf-should-you-have-large-maxbufferpoolsize-value-for-large-messages for WCF specific setting

Comment: yes indeed, but it only fails "sometimes", so this setting is not blocking us for every request, the WCF settings is known to us but not solving the problem